# infinite array list of user entries

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to have an `ArrayList` that records user entries and ends when it receives a **non-integer** value but I am getting an **infinite** loop and I don't know why.

```java
public class Tryout1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList entries = new ArrayList();
        Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter numbers");
        int i = obj1.nextInt();
        boolean accumulating = obj1.hasNextInt(); //check int

        while(accumulating) {
            entries.add(i);
        }                                                                                
        System.out.println(entries);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move your check inside the loop, so it will check every time before the next loop is executed.
In your code, the check is only performed once.

```java
public class tryout1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList entries = new ArrayList();
        Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter numbers");
        
        do {
             // get the next int
             int i = obj1.nextInt();
             entries.add(i);
        } while (obj1.hasNextInt()); // <- check here for nextInt

        System.out.println(entries);
    }
}
```